# Export series of images from feature collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I am hoping to export a series of Landsat8 NDVI images. I uploaded a shape file and created a FeatureCollection from it containing each of the regions that I am interested in creating a separate image for. In my current export line, it creates one GeoTIFF file with all the cities, but what I would like is a seprate image for each city.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: greenest,
  description:'ndvi_2021',
  region:cities,
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ee.Export` is a client side function, so you have fetch the name of the cities and iterate over them. You can do it synchronously using `.getInfo` or asynchronously using `evaluate`. My example will be with the latter. In my example, `name` is the column that holds the name of the cities.

```
var name_column = 'name'
var cities_names = cities.aggregate_array(name_column)
cities_names.evaluate(function(names){
  // names is a list so you have to iterate over it
  for (var n in names) {
    var name = names[n];
    // filter cities with city name
    var city = ee.Feature(cities.filter(ee.Filter.eq(name_column, name)).first())
    // export city
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: greenest,
      description:'ndvi_2021_'+name,
      region:city.geometry(),
      crs: projection.crs,
      crsTransform: projection.transform,
    });
  }
})
```

a toy example here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd26db21590d8313ab17bec40c135c38